# All rows of a Datagridview to a IList<Object>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns that has numbers and string as values. How do I get all the data in a row and place it in a single IList. If it is not in a datagridview, this is how I would do it -

```
var formula1 = "=SUM(B3:B5)";
var formula2 = "=SUM(C3:C5)";
var formula3 = "=MAX(D3:D5)";

List<object> list1 = new List<object>() { "Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date" };
List<object> list2 = new List<object>() { "Wheel", "20.50", "4", "3/1/2016" };
List<object> list3 = new List<object>() { "Door", "15", "2", "3/15/2016" };
List<object> list4 = new List<object>() { "Engine", "100", "1", "3/20/2016" };
List<object> list5 = new List<object>() { "Totals", formula1, formula2, formula3 };
IList<IList<Object>> list = new List<IList<Object>>() { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 };

ValueRange VRange = new ValueRange();
VRange.Range = range;
VRange.Values = list;
```

But if it the values are in a datagridview, I don't know how to do it anymore. Can you please teach a noob. Thank you.

Comment: As of now how you are populating the `datagridview`

Comment: If I do it the way I do it above, I can populate the "list" but if the values are in a datagridview, I don't know how to do it already.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with your list. You can create a list of DataGridViewRows, or you can create a dedicated class for your objects and store them in your list, or you can create dynamic ExpandoObjects... with more details, maybe you'll get more answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq to create a `List<List<object>>` from your `DataGridView` this way:

```
var list = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => !r.IsNewRow)
              .Select(r => r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.Value).ToList())
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time. I got it like this...

```
        IList<IList<Object>> list = new List<IList<Object>>() { };
        for (var i = 0; i < dgvAttendance.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            List<object> lists = new List<object>() { dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
                dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), 
                dgvAttendance.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() };
            list.Add(lists);
        }

        ValueRange VRange = new ValueRange();
        VRange.Range = range;
        VRange.Values = list;
```